# How to load page sections using Ajax and Jquery in ASP.Net MVC 3 razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

I am working on ASP.Net MVC 3 website which uses Razor view engine and Jquery

On homepage (or any page for that matter) I want to load sections of content using **ajax**, something like iGoogle.

I mean on page load

- I want to call some HttpGet action methods each of which returns some
  Html content
- Until I get response these Div's showing "loading" graphics.

I am aware of Ajax.BeginForm and Ajax.ActionLink but in both the cases I need to click some UI element; I do not know how to use them on page load/ document.Ready?

I will be thankful even if I get some direction and not exact/complete code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, lets give you some direction, I'm going to show some code in jquery because its easy enough. lets go.

Html

```
<div id="SomeContent"> </div>
```

In your view

```
$(function(){ // this runs on on page load
    LoadData('#SomeContent', @Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName"));
});
```

in a javascript library file

```
function LoadData(target, url){
  $.ajax({  
   beforeSend: startAnimation(target),
   url : url,
   success : function(result){ $(target).html(result); },
   complete  : stopAnimation(target)   
});
}

function startAnimation(target){
  //..add a loading image on top of the target  
}

function stopAnimation(target){
  // remove the animation gif or stop the spinning, etc.
}
```

your server side code

```
public ActionResult ActionName() {
    ... do things to get your model populated ...
    return PartialView("SomeView", yourmodel);
}
```

additional thoughts:

- this rough code loads a partial view into a div. The asychonous call begins when the dom is ready.
- see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for jquery ajax documentation
- i like to use spin.js to show a loading icon becuase it is so darn easy and small.

Comment: Thank for such a detailed explaination.